# "Class template has already been defined" when making similar but different specializations

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-specialization

I have two class specializations. I want one of them to be used when T::A exists and the other to be used when T::B exists, which should be multually exclusive in practice. I am using std::void_t< decltype( ... ) > to test for existence. I expect that expression to fail to evaluate for either one or the other specialization, and so I expect SFINAE to cause one of the specializations to be ignored.

```cpp
template< typename T, typename Enable = void >
class C{};

template< typename T >
class C< T, std::void_t< decltype( T::A ) > > {};

template< typename T >
class C< T, std::void_t< decltype( T::B ) > > {};
```

However, MSVC just gives me

```
(On line containing T::B): error C2953: 'C<T,void>': class template has already been defined
(On line containing T::A): note: see declaration of 'C<T,void>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `void_t` is always `void`, so there is no difference between first and those two

Comment: But the documentation for std::void_t specifically says that this kind of thing is its purpose: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t

Comment: Are `T::A` and `T::B` _actually_ mutually exclusive in your real code though?

Comment: The compile errors occur without trying to even use the class on any actual types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang also rejects this code, but not GCC. This is not the first time I'm seeing problems with `std::void_t`.

I would stay away from it, and prefer `decltype(void(T::A))`.

Or you can define your own robust `void_t` (code taken from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t)):

```
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type; };
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;
```

Comment: Replacing void_t with this implementation does seem to work around the issue. Do you think this is a bug in MSVC's compiler, or in their STL implementation? Any idea if there's a way to report it?

Comment: gcc will not select either template with `std::void_t` or with your `void_t`. It will select default template.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie [Works for me](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/KjqcMdnGr), with both `void_t` flavors. Are you perhaps defining `A` and `B` as types?

Comment: @JohnHaggerty I believe the defintion is fixed in the standard, but this could be a compiler bug. You could try filing it and see what happens. You could also report this to Clang. Be sure to check for existing reports first.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat scratch it, seems `void_t` mechanics is at odd with visibility of `T::A` , `T::B`.  They should be `public`. It might be related to OP's issue.

Comment: @JohnHaggerty By "fixed in the standard" I mean it requires the specific definition (the one without the helper struct).