# Why do we need to wrap evaluating expression inside void(...) in this template function implementation?

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to implement a template function to check whether the input type can be working with `ostream::operator<<` thus I can print such type out.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct HasOstreamOperator : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct HasOstreamOperator<T, decltype(void(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>()))> : std::true_type {};

struct NonOstreamCompatibleType { int v; };

int main()
{
    if constexpr (HasOstreamOperator<float>::value) {
        std::cout << "float is compatible" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "float is not compatible" << std::endl;
    }

    if constexpr (HasOstreamOperator<NonOstreamCompatibleType>::value) {
        std::cout << "NonOstreamCompatibleType is compatible" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "NonOstreamCompatibleType is not compatible" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Ref on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sce765bnT).

The result shown as

```
float is compatible
NonOstreamCompatibleType is not compatible
```

Question is if I take that `void(...)` out and that line would become

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct HasOstreamOperator<T, decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>())> : std::true_type {};
```

now the result is `not compatible` for both `float` and `NonOstreamCompatibleType`.
Why do we need to wrap such expression inside `void(...)`?
Please feel free if this needs to be related to any certain section inside C++ standard, please also provide me section to look at.

Comment: Do you understand how template specializations work? You're passing (implicitly) `void` as the second argument, so the specialization must also specify `void` to be selected.

Comment: That technique is superseded by C++20 concept.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I still dont get it why do we need to wrap expression with `void(...)` if `decltype(<expression>)` would produce a different type rather than `void` thus it would choose the second template implementation anyway, so it would be true case. Is there something to be done with treating the expression to be validly evaluated ? or just to satisfy compiler? Please englight me on this.

Comment: *"would produce a different type rather than void thus it would choose the second template implementation anyway"* Why would it? You pass `void` as the second argument, and if specialization specifies something else as the second argument, it's not going to be used?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks! I realize what you have mentioned now. I do miss certain understanding about template specialization.

Comment: The pattern name is **SFINAE**. It's outdated and has many different implementations. The role of this pattern is to constrain templates and disallow its instantiation for unsuitable types. From C++20 on you can achieve that using `concept`s with much  more ease and readability. Just Let SFINAE rest in peace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call `HasOstreamOperator<float>` instantiates the following type

```
HasOstreamOperator<float, void>
```

Now the only reason for the specialization to be selected is to be ... more specialized that the base template:

```
base template : HasOstreamOperator<float, void>
                                         ^^^ due to the default argument

specialization: HasOstreamOperator<float, expression>
```

and that can only happen if `expression == void`. You'd be better off using constraints through concepts (requires clauses and all that stuff can facilitate more than the binary true/false case) but since you ask for formal documentation take a look at the [`void_t` class](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) which is a standard class for implementing the pattern you mention:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, class = void>
struct HasOstreamOperator : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct HasOstreamOperator<
  T, 
  std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>())>
> : std::true_type {};
```

Here it's evident that all you do is using `void` as machinery to check if an expression is valid. If not the specialization is removed from the candidate set. If yes, it evaluates to `void` and beats the base simply by virtue of being a specialization.

Comment: Note that `void_t` is worse than what OP uses, some of its usages break in weird ways on some compilers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74553866/2752075

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thank for this notice. Well noted.