# How to fix this void_t issue with templated class?

Tags: c++, c++17, void-t

I have code like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct S1{};

struct S2{
    void rbegin(){}
    void rend(){}
};

template<typename S>
struct S3{
    void rbegin(){
        S().rbegin();
    }

    void rend(){
        S().rend();
    }
};

template<typename, typename = void>
constexpr bool is_reverse_iterable = false;
 
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_reverse_iterable<
                T,
                std::void_t<
                    decltype(std::declval<T>().rbegin()),
                    decltype(std::declval<T>().rend())
                >
> = true;

#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << is_reverse_iterable<S1> << '\n'; // print 0, correct
    std::cout << is_reverse_iterable<S2> << '\n'; // print 1, correct

    std::cout << is_reverse_iterable<S3<S1> > << '\n'; // print 1, wrong !!!
    std::cout << is_reverse_iterable<S3<S2> > << '\n'; // print 1, correct

//  S3<S1>().rbegin(); // not compiles
    S3<S2>().rbegin();
}
```

Example is copy / paste from cppreference.com website, however, `is_reverse_iterable<S3<S1> >` is set to true and this is wrong.

How can I fix this?

Godbolt link: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qjG46EWsq

Comment: Which cppref page?

Comment: copy / paste is not 1:1
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods of `S3` are not SFINAE-friendly. (During SFINAE, the compiler won't look inside the function body for substitution errors. It'll either ignore them if the function body isn't needed yet, or fail with a hard error on them if the body is needed, e.g. if the return type is `auto`.)

In C++20 you would fix them like this:

```
template <typename S>
struct S3
{
    void rbegin() requires requires{S().rbegin();}
    // or: void rbegin() requires is_reverse_iterable<S>
    {
        S().rbegin();
    }

    void rend() requires requires{S().rend();}
    {
        S().rend();
    }
};
```

In C++17 you need to do something like this:

```
template <typename S, typename = void>
struct S3_Base {};

template <typename S>
struct S3_Base<S, std::enable_if_t<is_reverse_iterable<S>>>
{
    void rbegin()
    {
        S().rbegin();
    }

    void rend()
    {
        S().rend();
    }
};

template <typename S>
struct S3 : S3_Base<S>
{};
```

Another C++17 option:

```
template <typename S>
struct S3
{
    template <typename SS = S, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<S, SS>, decltype(void(SS().rbegin()), nullptr)> = nullptr>
    // or template <typename SS = S, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<S, SS> && is_reverse_iterable<SS>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
    void rbegin()
    {
        S().rbegin();
    }

    template <typename SS = S, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<S, SS>, decltype(void(SS().rend()), nullptr)> = nullptr>
    void rend()
    {
        S().rend();
    }
};
```

Comment: I can not believe in C++17 you will need to do something similar to C++11 :)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/7bcsWfMe5

Comment: @Nick Yep, C++17 doesn't help with SFINAE. Even the `void_t` thing is [jank](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74553866/2752075), and `decltype(void(...))` is more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

It's not wrong, you declare the functions uncondionally. The fact the their definition will be ill-formed doesn't change the fact their declarations always exist. SFINAE (what `void_t` works with) only deals with the existence of declarations.

If you want `S3` to report correctly, you need to make it SFINAE friendly. For example:

```
template<typename S>
struct S3{
    template<typename T = S, decltype(std::declval<T>().rbegin(), 0) = 0>
    void rbegin(){
        S().rbegin();
    }

    template<typename T = S, decltype(std::declval<T>().rend(), 0) = 0>
    void rend(){
        S().rend();
    }
};
```

Now both members only participate in overload resolution if the wrapped type can make the call. This is of course only *one* way to (ab)use additional template definitions to make class definitions SFINAE friendly.

Comment: Most annoying is that some compilers may ignore unused declartions (an IFNDN case) and not only OP code may be acceped and work, if they are lucky, quite a number of SFINAE mistakes can stay hidden.